# How to add css class with it's value in Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a AngularJS Directive that uses jQuery DatePicker plugin.
I would like to use only months and years from DatePicker.

It is possible when writing following css style into html page before input tag.

```
<div>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <input type="text" ng-model="xMonth" month-year/>
              {{ xMonth }}
</div>
```

but I would like to set that css inside directive. Tried to use clause
  $('#ui-datepicker-div').toggleClass('.ui-datepicker-calendar', 
                                      'display: none');
but i didn't work.

How to set that css inside Directive?

```
angular.module('phonecatDirectives', [])
    .directive('monthYear', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var elem = angular.element(element);
            elem.datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm-yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                maxDate: +0,
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var month, year;
                    month = $(".ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    year = $(".ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('nodays');
                },
                beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                    var dateString, options;
                    dateString = $(this).val();
                    options = {};
                    if (dateString.length > 0) {
                        options.defaultDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-" + 
                      $(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"), "01-" + dateString);
                    }

                    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').toggleClass('.ui-datepicker-calendar', 
                      'display: none');

                    if ($(input).hasClass('nodays')) {
                        $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('nodays');
                    } else {
                        $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('nodays');
                        $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'mm.yy');
                    }
                    return options;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Best Regards
Dave

Comment: can you post Fiddle/Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with AngularJS but how you are using [`jQuery.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch).

This method is used to toggle (by adding or removing) a CSS selector **class name**, not individual CSS properties.

You can add `display:none` to an element using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value) or the functionally equivalent [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide the selected class. Furthermore, you need to target the element by CSS selector, not by element ID. The `#` prefix selects by element ID, `.` prefix selects by CSS selector.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-div').hide(); // or $('.ui-datepicker-div').css({display: 'none'});
```

Comment: I tried both hide and css methods but they didn't resolve situation.

Comment: To be honest, I found the selector `#ui-datepicker-div` to be strange, because that targets a specific element by `id`, which seems unlikely to be what you want. So maybe therein lies your problem. However, your HTML example is not sufficient because it doesn't look anything like what your code is describing to do. So we need a clearer example (something posted to plunkr.co or jsfiddle.net would be best). That being said, `css` and `hide` work, you just have to be sure you're targeting the right element.

Comment: What i'm going to is to use jQuery Datepicker in Angular so, that it does not show days, only months and years. That is possible when declaring  <style type="text/css">
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
        } </style> in html page BUT it affects then to all datepickers in HTML page. And I don't want that. So, instead I want to make a Directive which says that "only months and years" are shown. If there exists other Datepicker's in same HTML page they show days like DatePickers do.

Comment: OK, I sort of missed it. You need to change `$('#ui-datepicker-div').hide()` (or css, if you used that) to `$('.ui-datepicker-div').hide()`. Prefixing it with `#` selects by element ID. Prefixing with `.` selects by CSS selector, which is what you want.